# Possible to specify a priority namespace when there are ambiguous class names?

Tags: .net, namespaces

I am working on a web page that is using two namespaces that have a `Label` class:

- Micofosoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Label
- System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label

I had some code similar to the following:

```
Label lbl_Name = new Label();
```

that I was forced to change to:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lbl_Name = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label();
```

because I was getting the error:

> 'Label' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' and
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Label'

I am aware that I can "alias" (not sure if that's the right term) the namespace so that I don't have to have the whole thing in front of my class like so:

```
using UI = System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

But I was wondering if there is anyway to specify that I want to always use one namespace if there is a conflict.  Is there some way to specify that one namespace should come out on top if there is a conflict?

Comment: I do not think there is a way, but I am starring this for the unlikely event that an answer may pop up.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the reference to the less priority without causing too much pain?

Comment: Using TheNameSpace for the default, and fully qualified namespace for the other(s). I'd be interested tho if anyone knows a way to prioritize Namespace in order to overcome the ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `using` declarations to create aliases for types within a single file:

```
using SharePointLabel = Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Label;
using WebControlLabel = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label;
```

Then:

```
WebControlLabel lbl_Name = new WebControlLabel();
```